# Change in title for tag questions pages

Tags: feature-request

The title for the active questions pages has changed from e.g. "(4) Newest 'java' Questions" to "(4) Recently Active 'java' Questions".

The new title is more accurate. However, it is also longer. This matters to me, because I keep tabs open for several tags, and like to use the tab headers to see at a glance which tags have new activity. The longer boilerplate makes it less likely that the tab will have room for the tag.

One option would be to revert to the less accurate "Newest". Better still, put the changing information, the number of questions with recent activity and the tag, first. Move the boilerplate, the information that is the same all the time for every tag, regardless of how it is worded, to the end of the title.

Comment: sounds like you're addicted :P and also trying to be the fastest gun in the world.. Don't worry, you'll get tired of it at some point. Btw. you can set up a feed in one tab that will list all the new questions in all the tags youre interested in...Could that possibly be a resolution?

Comment: @vba4all I get tired of it from time to time - when I do, I walk away for a while. The tags have very different activity levels - an interesting "double" question would be scrolled out of sight under a flood of "java" questions if I combined them.

Comment: Categorize them in two tables in the feed..

Comment: More like 5 tables - I usually follow java, floating-point, double, algorithm, and arduino.